# How to install gloobus preview in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, gloobus-preview

I switched to ubuntu 14.04 and want quick preview. Can I  install gloobus preview in 14.04.
And How?

Note: I am not looking for gloobus alternative because I am already using gnome-sushi

Answer (score 2):

For 14.10 the following repository worked for me

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gloobus-preview
```

you might add these programs too

```
sudo apt-get install unoconv gnumeric
```

for previous versions of ubuntu, [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/04/gloobus-preview-update-brings-gtk3-and.html) article seems to talk about how to get it working